# ".accdb" has become corrupted

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

My program works fine inserting stuff in .accdb file, updating it etc. Everything is working properly until I add another field in .accdb type "Calculated Field" Whenever I do this my program can no longer open the .accdb. It's throwing error that the database has become corrupted.
This happens by simply  adding the field in the database, without changing any coding in my program.
Has anyone come around this issue? Is there a way to fix it?

I'm inserting "Column1","Column2","Column3","Column4","Column5" and the sixth Column has a Calculated Field where Column1 + Column2 etc.

Comment: [Calculated fields belong in queries, not tables.](http://allenbrowne.com/casu-14.html)

Comment: ~Much appreciated.